# How can I safely disable Intel RST?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, intel-rst, dualboot

I want to dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. But I can't do it because I have Intel RST on. So how can I turn it off without causing any harm to system? I have Lenovo IdeaPad laptop, which has one disk.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd just like to comment somewhere in this chain that Lenovo doesn't call it `iRST` in the BIOS, they call it `RAID`, and its opposite is `AHCI`. That may be super obvious to some, for me I had to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn it off in the BIOS, I have seen the option in MSI laptops but not in Dell laptops, so I would assume it depends on the manufacturer and probably the model too.

For example, these are the steps for Acer Aspire 3 series:

> If you find software incompatibilities with Intel Rapid Start
>   Technology (iRST), you can disable this energy-saving sleep mode in
>   the BIOS:
>
> ```
> Power on the system. As soon as the first logo screen appears, immediately press the F2 key, or the DEL key if you have a desktop, to
> ```
>
> enter the BIOS.
>       Use the ARROW KEYS to navigate to iRST.
>       Use the ARROW KEYS to select iRST Support. Press ENTER to change it to Disabled.
>       Press the F10 key to save changes and restart the system.
>
> NOTE
>
> These BIOS options are only available on models with a conventional
>   hard disk and additional 20GB SSD. It is not possible to configure
>   iRST in the BIOS for models with a single large SSD.

Source: https://za.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16631/~/disable-intel-rapid-start-technology