# I accidentally installed Linux on my Intel Optane SSD. How can I newly install Windows 10 and configure Intel Optane Memory properly?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, optane

I am fairly new to computers so excuse any terminology mistakes I make.

I had a PC running Windows 10 with Intel Optane Memory setup. For reference, I didn't really know about this or what it was before.

It's a 1 TB hard drive, so I thought I might partition it and try to dual-boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows. However, I ran into a problem as I was trying to install it. I got this error message:

> This computer uses Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu. For instructions, open this page: help.ubuntu.com/rst

I tried following the first solution on [this AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems) post. However, when I booted to Windows, it immediately went into recovery mode. I switched the SATA controller and tried all of the recovery options, but it looked like my Windows was gone.

I have a Windows bootable CD, so I thought I'd just install Ubuntu over everything and install Windows later. I turned off RST and went to install it, but saw it installed with only 14 GB of space on an SSD, which was strange to me. After some inspection, I discovered this was the Intel Optane Memory SSD.

I'm really worried I screwed up the Optane Memory, and I would still like to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows but just Windows with Optane working would be a good start. Does anybody know if this is possible? Can I reconfigure it so it works for me?

Much thanks.

CLARIFICATION: My main concern is installing Windows and configuring Optane memory. If that is possible, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/471523 and https://superuser.com/questions/738722 and https://superuser.com/questions/1559194 and https://superuser.com/questions/1560165/how-to-safely-disable-intel-rapid-storage-technology-in-uefi-bios

Comment: You need to switch back to RAID mode, in order to boot Windows or at least reinstall it, and then switch to AHCI mode within Windows.  Once you do that you can switch it back to SATA (ACHI) mode.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think so at least to my knowledge, unless there's some link I'm missing. I'm wondering if there is a way to newly install Windows so that Optane works with it. I don't actually know what RAID and AHCI have to do with that.

Comment: @Ramhound Wait, so I will install Windows, and as long as I'm in RAID mode, the Intel Optane Memory will work? It currently has Ubuntu installed on it. How do I fix that?

Comment: You obviously can’t keep that particular installation, and you can’t use Optane within Windows, and dual-boot Ubuntu.  You basically are using a cache SSD as a system drive (Optane only comes in 16GB and 32GB variations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing from RAID to AHCI and Windows 7 will not boot](https://superuser.com/questions/471523/changing-from-raid-to-ahci-and-windows-7-will-not-boot)

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, that's okay, but is it possible to recover Optane and set it up to work with just Windows after I overwrote it as a system drive? That's really my main question

Comment: @music2myear I don't think so, I want to figure out how to recover Optane and use it with a fresh Windows installation after I overwrote it.

Comment: @Ramhound "Optane only comes in 16GB and 32GB variations" FYI 900p has 280 GB and 480 GB versions.

Comment: @gronostaj - Optane has confusing branding.  Heck, I might be confused by what the author has, but a Optane Memory Drive is one of two sizes.  They also have SSDs under the Optane brand. Based on “Optane memory” is suspect it’s 16/32 GB cache drive with a larger drive.  Perhaps if the author clarified what hardware?

Comment: @Ramhound Well from the disks app in Ubuntu, the model is INTEL MEMPEK1J016GAD so I'm assuming that means 16 GB cache drive. Asking again though, if I reinstall Windows, can I reconfigure Optane to work with it?

Comment: @SubhasishMukherjee Optane drives aren't meant or intended to be OS drives - if you have the 16GB or 32GB versions, that is not enough storage to run Windows. You can configure Optane to work with Windows following a reinstall, else how would an OEM configure it prior to shipment? Both the OEM and Intel will have how to configure the Optane drive following a Windows install/reinstall on their respective sites. Drive configuration types [RAID (which is RST) and AHCI] are not hot-swappable, and if switching from one to the other, a reinstall of the OS will be required AFAIK.

Comment: @JW0914 - It is possible to switch from RST to ACHI without reinstalling Windows

Comment: @Ramhound How do you do so, because if it's changed in the BIOS/UEFI firmware from one to the other, Windows and WinRE won't boot?

Comment: You change it within Windows before you change it within the firmware.  See the 4 duplicates